# Access MessageResources from javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, localization

Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215920/localization-with-jquery) remain the "only" way to localize a javascript/jquery text or is there another way to access the MessageResources from javascript/jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technique described at that link is a generic way to access strings in a JavaScript scope. So the example is not the "only" way at all.

If your question is whether JavaScript or jQuery has a built-in method for handling localization/translation of message strings, then I suppose the answer is no. In order to access your message resources (which I assume are sitting in your back end, or in a file somewhere?) you will have to load them into your JavaScript scope somehow and access them in some meaningful way.

This could be coded any way you like, but there are a number of projects designed to standardize the approach. Take a look at [1i8next](http://jamuhl.github.io/i18next/)  It has [jQuery integration](http://jamuhl.github.io/i18next/pages/doc_jquery.html) too.