# How can I put PHP code to HTML using JavaScript?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, ajaxform

I making ajax request on my form in wordpress/woocommerce. I'm trying to show error message when user haven't been found. I tried to do it using the function `username_exist()`, but it doesn't work. The only way i find to do that is use `error:` in ajax-request and then past any message i want. But the problem is that i can't translate this message. I tried to put to the message `<?php wc_print_notices() ?>` but it shows as comment. Please help me solve this problem.
I have this code:

html form:

```
<form class="login" id="login" method="post">
  <p class="status_login">
  </p>
  <div class="form-field">
    <label for="user_login" class="label"><?php esc_html_e('Username or email address', 'woocommerce'); ?>&nbsp;<span
        class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class=" h-full-width c-h" name="user_login" id="user_login" autocomplete="user_login"
      value="<?php echo (!empty($_POST['username'])) ? esc_attr(wp_unslash($_POST['username'])) : ''; ?>" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-field"><label for="user_pass"><?php esc_html_e('Password', 'woocommerce'); ?>&nbsp;<span
        class="required">*</span></label>
    <input class=" h-full-width c-h" type="password" name="user_pass" id="user_pass" autocomplete="current-password" />
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <label class="woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox woocommerce-form-login__rememberme">
      <input class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox" name="rememberme" type="checkbox"
        id="rememberme" value="forever" /> <span><?php esc_html_e('Remember me', 'woocommerce'); ?></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <?php wp_nonce_field('ajax-login-nonce', 'security'); ?>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn--primary h-full-width" name="login"
      value="<?php esc_attr_e('Log in', 'woocommerce'); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Log in', 'woocommerce'); ?></button>
  </div>
  <div class="hr"></div>
  <div class="foot">
    <a
      href="<?php echo esc_url(wp_lostpassword_url()); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Lost your password?', 'woocommerce'); ?></a>
  </div>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
  $j.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: ajax_login_object.ajaxurl,
    data: {
      'action': 'ajaxlogin', //calls wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin
      'username': $j('#user_login').val(),
      'password': $j('#user_pass').val(),
      'security': $j('#login #security').val()

    },
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data)
      $j('.status_login').html(data.message);
      if (data.error == false) {
        $j('.status_login').html(data.message);
        document.location.href = ajax_login_object.redirecturl;
      }
    },
    error: function (msg) {
      $text = '<?php (Hello, world) ?>'
      $j('.status_login').html('<?php wc_print_notices() ?>);
    },
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

php code:

```
function ajax_login_init()
        {


            wp_enqueue_script('ajax-login-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/ajax_form.js', array('jquery'), null, true);

            wp_localize_script('ajax-login-script', 'ajax_login_object', array(
                'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
                'redirecturl' => "//" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
                'loadingmessage' => '<div class="alert alert-success">' . __('checking', 'malik') . '
  </div>'
            ));
            add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin', 'ajax_login');
        }
        if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
            add_action('init', 'ajax_login_init');
        }
        require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/user.php';
        function ajax_login()
        {
            if (!check_ajax_referer('ajax-login-nonce', 'security')) {

                echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'message' => '<div class="alert alert-danger">' . __('Session token has
    expired, please reload the page and try again', 'malik') . '</div>'));

                die();
            }

            // Nonce is checked, get the POST data and sign user on
            $info = array();
            $info['user_login'] = !empty($_POST['username']) ? sanitize_user(trim($_POST['username'])) : NULL;
            $info['user_password'] = !empty($_POST['password']) ? sanitize_text_field(trim($_POST['password'])) : NULL;
            $info['remember'] = true;
            $user_signon = wp_signon($info, false);
            $user_login = sanitize_user($_POST['username']);
            $user_pass = sanitize_text_field(trim($_POST['password']));
            $user_exists = false;

            if (username_exists($user_login)) {
                $user_exists = true;
                $user = get_user_by('login', $user_login);
            } elseif (email_exists($user_login)) {
                $user_exists = true;
                $user = get_user_by('email', $user_login);
            } elseif (!empty($user_login) && !empty($user_pass)) {
                $error = new WP_Error('no_user_found', 'Username or Email was not found, please try again', 'Page Data');
            } else {
                echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'message' => '<div class="alert alert-danger">' .
                    $user_signon->get_error_message() . '</div>'));
                die();
            }


            if ($user_exists === true) {
                $user_id = $user->ID;
                $user_data = get_userdata($user_id);
                $username = $user_data->user_login;
                $userpass = $user_data->user_pass;
            } elseif (is_wp_error($user_signon) || $user_exists === false) {
                echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'message' => '<div class="alert alert-danger">' .
                    $user_signon->get_error_message() . '</div>'));
                die();
            } else {
                wp_clear_auth_cookie();
                wp_set_current_user($user_id, $username);
                wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);
                echo json_encode(array('error' => false, 'message' => '<div class="alert alert-success">' . __('Login successful,
    reloading page...', 'malik') . '</div>'));

                die();
            }
            die();
        }
```

I and when login=faled i have this:

```
<p class="status_login">
<!--?php  wc_print_notices() ?-->
      </p>
```

Comment: You need to run the PHP code in a location where it will be interpreted and executed, e.g. a .php file. From the behaviour you describe it would appear that you've put it in a .js file instead.

Comment: yes, i past it in .php file, but using .js. I want to show message using php to make it possible translate it

Comment: `$text = <?php echo "'(hello, world)'";`

Comment: $text - jquery variable, so it doesn't work unfortunally...

Comment: if you want that for localization, this link can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215920/localization-with-jquery

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Localization with JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215920/localization-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand, that jquery is client side code and interpretated by the browser. PHP is server side and interpretated by the server. What you need is a server call to get the rendered result of the php code. You could make an $.ajax-call (or native fetch-API) to get the result.

BUT: **DO NOT WRITE SCRIPTS**, that runs any PHP-code, recieved by an request-parameter. An evil person could use your script to damage your backend.

An example:

```
<form action="run.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="code" value="echo '(hello, world)'" />
    <input type="submit" value="execute"></form>
```

run.php could do this really bad thing:

```
<?php eval($_REQUEST['code']); ?>
```

Every user could call your script like this (outside your form, just calling this in a browser-addressbar):

```
https://domain.tld/run.php?code=unlink('/')
```

So: please understand the differences between client-side-code and server-side-code before producing code, that can damage your system.